# Can Minhashing be used as a Dimensionality Reduction Method?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, large-data

Let's say I have high dimensional data where the number of data points $N$ is $1,000,000$ and the dimensionality $D$ of the data is $1,000$. For each data point, a vector $v = (v_0, ..., v_n)$ of hashes is computed, where $n < D$, allowing the estimation of the Jaccard distance. This vector containing the hashes has lower dimensionality (which is of course what speeds up the estimation of the Jaccard distance). However, I wonder if this is an actual dimensionality reduction that could i.e. be used to speed up a logistic regression on the data?

Comment: What is $N$? What is $D$?

Comment: @Sycorax $N$ is the number of data points and $D$ their dimensionality. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of hashing you're suggesting to use?